# elasticsearch: Shard replica sizing is disparate

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

This morning, we were alerted that a few machines in a 4 node Elasticsearch clusters are running low on disk space. We're using 5 shards, with single replication.

The [status report](https://gist.github.com/pcsanwald/13bc1e2d9c51c58fdef9) shows index sizes that line up with the disk usage we're seeing. However, the confusing thing, is that the replicated shards are very out of line for shards 2 and 4. I understand that shard sizes can vary between replicas; however the size differences we are seeing are enormous:

```
"shards": {
   ...
      "2": [
  {
    "routing": {
      "state": "STARTED",
      "primary": true,
      "node": "LV__Sh-vToyTcuuxwnZaAg",
      "relocating_node": null,
      "shard": 2,
      "index": "eventdata"
    },
    "state": "STARTED",
    "index": {
      "size_in_bytes": 87706293809
    },
    ......
  },
  {
    "routing": {
      "state": "STARTED",
      "primary": false,
      "node": "U7eYVll7ToWS9lPkyhql6g",
      "relocating_node": null,
      "shard": 2,
      "index": "eventdata"
    },
    "state": "STARTED",
    "index": {
      "size_in_bytes": 42652984946
    },
```

Some interesting data points:

1. There's a lot of merging happening on the cluster at the moment. Could this be a factor? If merges make a copy of the index prior to merging, then that would explain a lot.
2. The bigger shard is almost exactly twice the size of the the smaller shard. coincidence? (I think not).

Why are we seeing indices at double the size of their replicas in our cluster? merging? some other reason?